# google map get all tiles locations at a specific location

Tags: android, google-maps

i am currently working on an app that require to temporary download google map for offline use .

as suggested here [using tileprovider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206719/how-to-save-google-map-in-android-and-how-to-use-tileprovider) i can render my own tiles for offline use

so basically suppose i have the following location latlng(10,10) and zoom level 2 ,how can i get  all tiles around a distance of 1km near this location .

as shown in this [post](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_2) i already know the equation required in order to convert latitude ,longitude  to a tile coordinates x,y,z but my problem is i don't know how to figure out what are all the tiles positions around a specific location of a range of 1km for example

Comment: This goes against the section 3.2.4.a of the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538148/how-to-download-specific-region-of-google-map-in-android/46569769?noredirect=1#comment93973989_46569769 it actually does temporary if you read the license agreement carefully

Comment: Just calc coords and zoom of tile which include all area that you need, then calc coords for 4 "subtiles" of  zoom+1 etc.